# convert datetime to date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DateTime object `2/19/2011 12:00:00 AM`. I want to convert this object to a string `19/2/2011`.

Please help me to convert DateTime to string format.

Comment: Is it `object` a `DateTime`? By convert, you mean you want a string formatted? How do you define the "the most possible answers"?

Comment: Do you want string formatting, or do you want just the date?

Comment: Please make your question *much, much* clearer. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I'm really not a person to complain about laziness (I'm myself lazy way too often), but this is clearly a case of not looking before asking, just look at how many related questions exist, with even **the exact same date format string** (and I have no doubt that this is what aswathi is after)

Comment: I think she meant "Best possible method"

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourObject.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Sandeep, then you'll have to use the `DateTime.TryParse()` method.

Comment: Hi Karel your solution is great works for me but I want to get date like ''19-Feb-2011". How can I get that?

Comment: Does ParseExact only accept this format 'MM/dd/yyyy'?

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10/1/2016 4:36:37 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
i get an error of
            String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @Fazal your day is "1" instead of "01" so change de format string from "dd" to "d"

Answer (score 31):

First of all, you don't convert a `DateTime` object to some format, you *display* it in some format.

Given an instance of a `DateTime` object, you can get a formatted string in that way like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 2, 19);
string formatted = date.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 22):

As everyone else said, but remember `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`!

```
string s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

OR escape the '/'.

Comment: What is the purpose of InvariantCulture here?

Comment: Not all the cultures use the / as a date separator. Some write dd-MM-yyyy. The framework converts the / in your format string to the date separator of the current culture (current at the time of execution). But you want to always use the / separator. The second option (OR escape...) is to "escape" the /, so that ToString doesn't consider it as a date separator but as a "fixed" char. You escape with '\', so it would be @"dd\/M\/yyyy" (the @ is because otherwhise you would have to escape the \, so "dd\\/M\\/yyyy"). All of them are quite unreadable, so it's better to fix the CultureInfo.

Answer (score 12):

You have to pass the CultureInfo to get the result with slash(/)

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 10):

DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") may give the date in dd-MM-yyyy format. This depends on your short date format. If short date format is not as per format, we have to replace character '-' with '/' as below:

```
 date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace('-','/');
```

Answer (score 7):

It's simple--`tostring()` accepts a parameter with this format...

```
DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method, that takes `datetime(format:01-01-2012 12:00:00)` and returns `string(format: 01-01-2012)`

```
public static string GetDateFromDateTime(DateTime datevalue){
    return datevalue.ToShortDateString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method, if you want a string representation of your date, with the correct formatting.

Like:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 02, 19);
string strDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

In [C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw&epi=a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xozb2s63cobiu00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw%29%28%29&irclickid=_cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xozb2s63cobiu00) you can use [DateOnly](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-dateonly-and-timeonly-in-dotnet-6).

```
DateOnly date = new(2011, 02, 19);
string output = date.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the string use -

```
DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

On my login form I am showing the current time on a label.

```
    public FrmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
    }

    private void tmrTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblHora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string currentdatetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse(YOUR_DATE_OBJECT).ToShortDateString();
```

ToShortDateString() method will help you convert DateTime To Just Date String,format dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
string dateTimeString = "21‎-‎10‎-‎2014‎ ‎15‎:‎40‎:‎30";
dateTimeString = Regex.Replace(dateTimeString, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);

string inputFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
string outputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = dateTime.ToString(outputFormat);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score -6):

this  is you need and all people

```
   string date  = textBox1.Text;

        DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        var date3 = date2.Date;
        var D = date3.Day;
      var M =  date3.Month;         
      var y = date3.Year;
      string monthStr = M.ToString("00");
      string date4 = D.ToString() + "/" + monthStr.ToString() + "/" + y.ToString();


      textBox1.Text = date4;
```