# Format string "yyyyMMdd" to "dd/MM/yyyy" from List c# .Net 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a string that I get from a source that represents a date and comes like this "19941201" **(Year+Month+Day)**.

I need it to be **"01/12/1994"** or even **"01-12-1994"**.

I am retrieving this data from a **List using linq**.

Is there a 'neat' way to do this? I use c# and .Net4.0
!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/5050141/1004522 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can simply do `datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: Thanks, this works for what I need! Just to complete the answer `CultureInfo` is imported from 'System.Globalization'.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

and read this [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime)

You will get a better understanding when you read up on rather than someone else doing it for you. I learnt the hard way

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ParseDate("19941201"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string ParseDate(string uglyDate)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(uglyDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DateTime.Parse() and DateTime.ToString() methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx