# How to change the string into datetime format in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a string which is "26052014153850" it is in the format of date month year hour minute second. i want to convert this to date and time format but its showing string is not recognized as valid date and time

```
string result ="26052014153850";
     DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(result, "dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm/ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert datetime to date format dd/mm/yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050102/convert-datetime-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact
               (result, "ddMMyyyyHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The format of the string representation must match the specified format **exactly**.  
Read [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) for more from MSDN.

Comment: capital "HH" will make it count 24 hours, "hh" would only count till 12.

Comment: @user2380844 Yes, I have changed. Good luck.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, adding description about the solution in the answer would make it easy to understand.