# Set field DateTime to show the date and time in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime, formatting

This code gets the date from the table to show in a table for the user

```
using System; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Security; 
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Form 
{
    public class RelUso
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
    public RelUso()
    {
        atribuiValores(row);
    }
    public RelUso(DataRow row)
    {
        assignValues(row);
    }
    protected void assignValues(DataRow row)
    {
        this.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]);
    }
}
```

It gets the date how it is in the database yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Can I do some method in the `DateTime` to change the formatting of the date to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: The `DateTime` does not have a format - it is just a value.  How it displays to the user depends on the culture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert datetime to date format dd/mm/yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050102/convert-datetime-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the DateTime structure to string using the following code:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
string str = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); //(For month use caps 'MM')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I put : Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");this.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Data"]); But nothing has changed

Comment: the Date field should be a string.