# Show only Date in Column of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datagridview

I have a **date** store in **MySQL** Database with the format `Datetime`.

I want to put **only** the date in one `DataGridView` but when I try i get the date with the following hours, something like:

```
29/06/2016 12:01:21
```

I tried to find the date directly from the **MySQL** query using the `DATE()` function, but it still does not work because in my `DataGridView` I see the date formatted as follows:

```
29/06/2016 00:00:00
```

Finally I tried side code to set the column, but without result

```
dataGridView.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

I use `DataSource` to "link" my data to my `DataGridView`.

---

This is the code:

```
var dataTable = listOfResult.ToDataTable(); //ToDataTable() Function that convert List into DataTable
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
dataGridView.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

The `listOfResult` is a list of such dynamic , where inside there are all the dates.

Function `ToDataTable()`

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
    {
        var data = items.ToArray();
        if (!data.Any()) return null;

        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var key in ((IDictionary<string, object>) data[0]).Keys)
            dt.Columns.Add(key);

        foreach (var d in data)
            dt.Rows.Add(((IDictionary<string, object>) d).Values.ToArray());

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050102/convert-datetime-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: @OffirPe'er - I use DataBinding to link my "date" to my DataGridView. I read from my database the date and the put into datagridview.

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: @Leopard - Added the code

Comment: What is `listOfResult`?

Comment: @Aimnox - A list of such dynamic , where inside there are all the dates

Comment: Have you checked that `ValueType = typeof(DateTime);` for the column ? Otherwise the format will fail silently. Also: Try to set those properties before loading the data. Also: where do you set the datatype of the DataTable column??

Comment: @TaW - I use DataSource, so i don't create manualy the columns. I try to use datagrid.Columns[1].ValueType = typeof(DateTime); but it doesn't work

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti I marked the question as duplicate of the linked post. The reason is exactly because the type of column is not `DateTime`. When you add a column using `Columns.Add("column name")`, the type of column will be `string` and so formatting will not apply. To solve the problem, you can use the method which is in linked post or simply fix your method to support type of properties. Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TaW's right. Set the DataType: replace

```
dt.Columns.Add(key);
```

with

```
dt.Columns.Add(key, typeof(DateTime));
```

for the desired columns.

Comment: I use DataSource, so i don't create manualy the columns.
I try to use `datagrid.Columns[1].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);` but it doesn't work

Comment: This is not about the DGV's columns but about the DataTable's column so I think this should work!

Comment: @TaW - I did as suggested, in the function that converts the list into `DataTable` I have conducted an audit that verifies if the data is of type `DateTime` in this case imposed the column, while creating as such