# How to change date format for label text

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.
In my database table named TOTAL there is column UPDATE whose data type is DATETIME. Its format is 03/20/2020

I pass this value to `Label1.text`. See below

```
const string query = "Select Top 1 [uppdate] From total";
cmd.CommandText = query;
con.Open();
using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        Label1.Text = "Last Update: " + rd["uppdate"].ToString();
```

But my site shows 03/20/2020 12:00:00 AM. I want to change it to 20.03.2020 without time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert datetime to date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050102/convert-datetime-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL complaint.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom format string:

```
 rd["uppdate"].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"); // case sensitive
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I have already tried your solution. But, it gives this error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments. While I was looking for a solution this error, I found the solution. I updated my post. Thank you!

Comment: Note: `rd["uppdate"]` [(see docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatarecord.item?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_IDataRecord_Item_System_String_) returns `System.Object`.  Use instead `rd.GetDateTime("uppdate")` [(see docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatarecord.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_IDataRecord_GetDateTime_System_Int32_) to get a `System.DateTime`; then you can call `ToString` on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Label1.Text = "Last Update: " + rd["uppdate"].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```